# exclude a certain path from all user searches

Tags: search, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Unfortunately we have a special folder named **"_archive"** in our repository everywhere. 
This folder has its purpose. But: When searching for content/documents we want to exclude it and every content beneath **"_archive"**.

So, what i want is to exclude the path and its member from all user searches. Syntax is easy with fts:

```
your_query AND -PATH:"//cm:_archive//*"
```

to test:
https://www.docdroid.net/RmKj9gB/search-test.pdf.html
take the pdf, put it into your repo twice:

- /some_random_path/search-test.pdf
- /some_random_path/_archive/search-test.pdf

In node-browser everything works as expected:

```
TEXT:"HODOR" AND -PATH:"//cm:_archive//*"
= 1 result

TEXT:"HODOR"
= 2 results
```

So, my idea was to edit search.get.config.xml and add the exclusion to the list of properties:

```
<search>
    <default-operator>AND</default-operator>
    <default-query-template>%(cm:name cm:title cm:description ia:whatEvent
        ia:descriptionEvent lnk:title lnk:description TEXT TAG) AND -PATH:"//cm:_archive//*"
    </default-query-template>
</search>
```

But it does not work as intended! As soon as i am using 'text:' or 'name:' in the search field, the exclusion seems to be ignored.

What other option do i have? Basically just want to add the exclusion to the base query after the default query template is used.

Version is Alfresco Community 5.0.d

thanks!

Comment: I've always had performance issues when using PATH queries, you don't? How big is your repo, circa?

Comment: the wiki says search can get slow and you might want to increase cache size. but i had no problem with it yet. I run this in a dev environment with 5gb of content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're mistaken what query templates are meant for. Take a look at the [Wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Full_Text_Search_Query_Syntax#Query_Templates).

So what you're basically doing is programmatically saying I've got a keyword and I want to match the keywords to the following metadata fields.

Default it will match **cm:name cm:title cm:description** etc. This can be changed to a custom field or in other cases to **ALL**.

So putting an extra AND or here of whatever won't work, cause this isn't the actual query which will be built. I can go on more about the query templates, but that won't do you any good.

In your case you'll need to modify the search.get webscript of Alfresco and the method called **function getSearchResults(params)** in search.lib.js (which get's imported).

Somewhere in at the end of the method it will do the following:

```
ftsQuery = '(' + ftsQuery + ') AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating" AND -TYPE:"st:site"' + ' AND -ASPECT:"st:siteContainer" AND -ASPECT:"sys:hidden" AND -cm:creator:system AND -QNAME:comment\\-*';
```

Just add your path to query to it and that will do.

Comment: I am using 5.0.d community - I don't have the mentioned method in search.get.js

Comment: The method is in search.lib.js, the search.get.js does an import.

Comment: What version are you working on? Are you sure this is working for 5.0.d?

Comment: It appears that in 5.0.d the line looks a bit different.
`ftsQuery = '(' + ftsQuery + ') AND -TYPE:"cm:thumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:failedThumbnail" AND -TYPE:"cm:rating" AND -TYPE:"st:site"' +
                                   ' AND -ASPECT:"st:siteContainer" AND -ASPECT:"sys:hidden" AND -cm:creator:system AND -QNAME:comment\\-*';`

Comment: Pff @user1429166 are you really going there? Use total commander or something else and find the search.lib.js in the jar file. Do we really need to do your work for you..... In this case the file is located in alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d.jar

Comment: @AxelFaust my bad, I've copied it probably from a different Alfresco version.